# How do I make a loop that commands the user to keep inputing a value until If conditions are met, with the aid of a try catch statement?

Tags: java

Im trying to tell the user to keep inputing the right value format until its done properly. I want to display to the user that if he/she has typed in the wrong format (number of values), he/she should try again and the system will ask the user to input new values. How do I do that with the following code below?

And is the while statement at the bottom valid (properly written)? Like if the exception isnt triggered, stop "do:ing"

P.S, I know that my code below looks awful, as I'm a mere beginner and do not know how to format code properly

```
public class PersonTidbok {

   public static void main(String[] args){


      Scanner console = new Scanner (System.in);

      System.out.print ("Welcome to your interface, please select of the following: " +
                        "\nP, T, L, S, A, Q"); 

  choice = console.next().charAt(0);

      switch (choice){

 case P:

      do{ 

      System.out.print (" enter persnr in the format of (YYYYMMDD));

        try{

        persnr = console.nextInt();

           if ( persnr.length != 8);

             throw new FormatException();
      }

                catch (FormatException exception){
                System.out.println(exception + "You printed wrong format, try again")); 
   }
}
   while (!FormatException);
}
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I loop until the user makes correct input on Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39524599/how-do-i-loop-until-the-user-makes-correct-input-on-java)

Comment: I appeal to reopen it as it is not only about looping until the user makes correct input but also about the correct format and how to throw/catch an exception.

Comment: Wow, two, things, I closed this thread since I believed it would get downvoted and which then I'd possibly banned lol. second, i can no longer post questions  :C I dont know if i can reopen this thread.

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash: Every problem is unique to a beginner developer, and I'm glad you helped the OP.  Unfortunately, Stack Overflow would be full of "Why doesn't my == compare Strings?", "Why does my Scanner skip the user input?", "How do I check user input for errors?", and so on.  I'm not sure where all the teachers and school help desks have gone, but they seem to have disappeared.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc - I couldn’t agree more. Thanks for your encouraging words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it as follows:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class PersonTidbok {
    public static void main(String[] argv) {
        Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean valid;
        char choice = '\0';
        String persnr;
        do {
            valid = true;
            System.out.print("Welcome to your interface, please select of the following (P, T, L, S, A, Q): ");
            String input = console.nextLine();
            if (input.length() != 1) {
                System.out.println("Invalid input. Try again.");
                valid = false;
            }
            choice = input.charAt(0);
        } while (!valid);

        switch (choice) {
        case 'P':
            do {
                valid = true;
                System.out.print("Enter persnr in the format of (YYYYMMDD): ");
                try {
                    persnr = console.nextLine();
                    if (!persnr.matches("[1-9]{1}[0-9]{7}")) {
                        throw new IllegalArgumentException("You printed wrong format, try again");
                    }
                    System.out.println("Processsing...");
                    // ...Processing of persnr should go here
                } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                    valid = false;
                }
            } while (!valid);
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("Wrong value for choice.");
        }
    }
}
```

**A sample run:**

```
Welcome to your interface, please select of the following (P, T, L, S, A, Q): a
Wrong value for choice.
```

**Another sample run:**

```
Welcome to your interface, please select of the following (P, T, L, S, A, Q): PT
Invalid input. Try again.
Welcome to your interface, please select of the following (P, T, L, S, A, Q): P
Enter persnr in the format of (YYYYMMDD): 01234567
You printed wrong format, try again
Enter persnr in the format of (YYYYMMDD): ancdefgh
You printed wrong format, try again
Enter persnr in the format of (YYYYMMDD): 20180912
Processsing...
```

Comment: can i ask you a question off topic, are you aware of a tool or a program of some sort that helps me to format code properly, in terms of "layout", "look", "design"?

Comment: @Zerinity What you're looking for is called an IDE software. They're crazy useful and powerful. VSCode and Sublime are popular. for Java, try the IDE called intelliJ IDEA and use the menu item Code>Reformat Code to adjust the visual layout of your code.